# Add data from textfield into arraylist and it forced closed my application

Tags: android, arraylist

I want to add data from the textfield into arraylist,but it force close when i trying to add the data from textfield,what error occur is with the part String name = editText.getText().toString();

```
 EditText editText;
 editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.insert);

                     String name = editText.getText().toString();

                     products.add(new Product(name,false));
```

i have a function that add the arraylist

```
     String[] dataArray;
    void fillData() {

      dataArray = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.ChecklistData);
      for(String productName : dataArray)
      {
        products.add(new Product(productName,false));
      }

  }
```

This is my logcat

```
05-15 20:52:00.628: E/AndroidRuntime(1117): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-15 20:52:00.628: E/AndroidRuntime(1117): java.lang.NullPointerException
05-15 20:52:00.628: E/AndroidRuntime(1117):     at com.example.checklist.MainActivity$3.onClick(MainActivity.java:102)
05-15 20:52:00.628: E/AndroidRuntime(1117):     at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage(AlertController.java:171)
05-15 20:52:00.628: E/AndroidRuntime(1117):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-15 20:52:00.628: E/AndroidRuntime(1117):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:213)
05-15 20:52:00.628: E/AndroidRuntime(1117):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5225)
05-15 20:52:00.628: E/AndroidRuntime(1117):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-15 20:52:00.628: E/AndroidRuntime(1117):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
05-15 20:52:00.628: E/AndroidRuntime(1117):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:741)
05-15 20:52:00.628: E/AndroidRuntime(1117):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:557)
05-15 20:52:00.628: E/AndroidRuntime(1117):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: String name = editText.getText().toString();

Answer (score 0):

> what error occur is with the part String name =
>   editText.getText().toString();

Frome your comments you say that line is 102

You have a `NullPointerException`. If this is the line where you have `NullPointerException` then `editText` is null.

Make sure `editText` is properly initialized

Comment: I have declared it in global area in my main class

Comment: @Jiazzyuser there is a difference between declaration and initialization. read on that

Comment: @Jiazzyuser you would have declared but not initialized

Comment: is it my initialization need to put it inside after the setContentview(); ?

Comment: @Jiazzyuser yes untill that getWindow returns null and findViewById fails. `int a;` declared. `a= 12` initialized

Comment: @Jiazzyuserand declared as a instance variable not globally. Its not global to the application. Your usage of global in this case is wrong